React-Query infinite retry loop
Facing an infinite render when a query fails using react-query. useQuery should only re-fetch if queryKey changes, or on request failure according to retry parameter.
Why is queryFn being re-executed?
Reproducible example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ilias-react-query-loop?file=src%2Fmain.tsx
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: { queries: { retry: false } },
});

const useFailingQuery = () =>
  useQuery({
    queryKey: ['static'],
    queryFn() {
      console.log('Fetching...');
      throw new Error('Fail');
      return {};
    },
  });

const Component = () => {
  useFailingQuery();
  return <h1>Component</h1>;
};

const App = () => {
  const { isLoading } = useFailingQuery();

  // This causes infinite query retry
  if (isLoading) {
    return <span>Loading...</span>;
  }

  return <Component />;
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <App />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

In the end, I need to render <Component /> only when useFailingQuery() is finished loading, and render a page-wide skeleton while it is loading.

There is a setting called retryOnMount (https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/framework/react/reference/useQuery#:~:text=retryOnMount%3A%20boolean) that is true by default. This is what is causing your loop. When the <Component /> mounts it triggers a refetch, the refetch makes isLoading true for a render, which unmounts the component, next render causes isLoading to be false, which mounts the component again and changes the isLoading to true.
The solution to your problem is setting retryOnMount to false in either the global config or the config for the particular query.
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: { queries: { retry: false, retryOnMount: false } },
});


Solved my issue! Maybe this is a question for the react query devs but why is it called retryOnMount? The component is not remounted, only rerendered?

While I couldn't figure out the useQuery() loop, a workaround is to always render the component:
const App = () => {
  const { isLoading } = useFailingQuery();

  return <>
    {isLoading && <span>Loading...</span>}
    <Component />
  </>;
};


Use Suspense? Same idea

The problem appears because of how you conditionally render your components that use the same query, and because components that are in error state are always considered "stale" (because they have no data yet). Here's what happens:

you render App, which triggers the failing query, and you render Loading...
when the query finishes with an error, isLoading is no longer true, so we proceed to render <Component />.
That component also triggers the failing query by calling useFailingQuery() again. Since there is no data yet, and a new component mounted, the query is put into a hard loading state, thus isLoading becomes true.
Now, react-query will inform all subscribers of the new state, so your App re-renders.
Because isLoading is now true again, you will unmount <Component /> and render Loading...

--> we are now back to point 1) of the list, and it will repeat infinitely.
So essentially, you're missing error handling somewhere in your component tree.
